# Using table joins to put seq no to the grouped items in the select SQL Query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

can any one help to solve this issue in SQL SERVER 2008. I want to put seq numbering to the grouped items in the select query result.

```
select a.grade, a.name, a.age, seqno  
from tab A join tab B on A.id = B.id 
[group based on Grade column]
```

The result should show as shown below.

```
SeqNo   Grade     Name    Age
-----   -----     ----    ---
  1      A        abc     23
  2      A        xyz      7
  1      B        dfg     34
  2      B        sxd     23
  3      B        vvv     56
```

In the below query, how i can join the second table and using a "join'

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [a.Grade] ORDER BY [a.Name]) AS 'SeqNo', 
       [a.Grade], [a.Name], [a.Age] 
FROM Employee a WITH (NOLOCK) 
ORDER BY  [a.Grade],[a.Name]
```

Comment: What "*second table*"? How is it related to `Employee`?

Comment: it is through id. I mentioned in the above query that A.id = B.id , being B is the second table.

Comment: it is through id col. ie, A.id = B.empid , being A is the first and B is the second table. That means, i am taking only the employees from Employee table that is only found in SecondTable by checking employee.id = secondtable.empid